# MySQL multiple queries InnoDB

Tags: php, mysql

I am new with InnoDB transactions. I am learning but I have a question about this.

```
<?php
include_once("../../../../../wp-config.php");
global $wpdb;
$cats_table     = $wpdb->prefix . "jb_menu_groups";
$relation       = $wpdb->prefix . "jb_relations";
$mysqli = new mysqli($wpdb->dbhost, $wpdb->dbuser, $wpdb->dbpassword, $wpdb->dbname);
if ($mysqli -> connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $mysqli -> connect_error;
    exit();
}

// Turn autocommit off
$mysqli -> autocommit(FALSE);

$mysqli -> query("DELETE FROM $cats_table WHERE id=6");
$mysqli -> query("DELETE FROM $relation WHERE groupid=3");

// Commit transaction
if (!$mysqli -> commit()) {
  echo "Commit transaction failed";

  exit();
}

$mysqli -> rollback();
$mysqli -> close();
?>
```

If I create one wrong query for testing the commit and rollback the code runs the other query with success.

How can I doe multiple queries in one transaction and If one query has an error do rollback and cancel the transaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally only worked with PDO and transactions, but this is how it should work with mysqli:

```
// start the transaction
$mysqli->autocommit(false);

$catQuery = $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM $cats_table WHERE id=6");
$relationQuery = $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM $relation WHERE groupid=3");

if ($catQuery && $relationQuery) {
    // in case the db server confirms the correctness of the queries, commit the transaction
    $mysqli->commit();
} else {
    // something went wrong
    $mysqli->rollback();
}

// don't forget to reset the transaction mode again, in case your app isn't ending here
$mysqli->autocommit(true);
```

Just be sure not to include `CREATE, ALTER or DROP` statements in a transaction, as this will commit the changes instantly.